# Google Analytics tracking the wrong site

Tags: google, google-analytics

I have multiple sites tracked in my profile - they each using different tracking ids of course.

However, one of my sites reports being visited by searchers using keywords completely unrelated by that site, but related to another site in my profile.  It also shows pages that are most accessed which are not on the website in question, but on the other website.

I have had a look at the tracking code in the head, and it is the correct code displayed by GA.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those pages that are showing up as most accessed from the other website surely have the other profile ID somewhere on the page.

1. View Source and search for any instances of 'UA-'
2. Check that you aren't using any plugins or extensions that provide analytics that might have the wrong profile id
3. Check you don't have any Flash widgets etc that might provide analytics separately (e.g. SWFAddress)

If none of those work, post a link to your pages.

Comment: Thanks, it was using an old version of GA tracking the wrong site.  The site has been using GA for about 2 years, and I've only seen the data being reported in the other site's GA reports in the last 2 weeks.  The problem I have now is that when I upload a correct index.php file, something is overwriting it with the old file.  It is a Joomla template index.php file, and I wouldn't think Joomla has this ability.  My web host is claiming it's not their fault.

Comment: Maybe you have a GA extension installed in your Joomla instance? One like this? http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/site-analytics/4300